# What is "MyToolWindow" in PhpStorm IDE?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have this weird panel in my PhpStorm which gives me a random number generator, but I can't find any setting or help regards it, nor it is in a plugin list. I wonder what is it and maybe I could use it for more than just a random number shuffler.

[image: my tool window, phpstorm]

I've tried searching thru settings and google any info about it, as well asking ChatGPT, but seems no one is having it except me :/

Comment: Check all **custom (not bundled by default)** plugins one by one until you find it. Just filter by `/downloaded` (IIRC) in the "Settings/Preferences | Plugins" screen. Show a screenshot of that. But yes -- no idea what plugin that might be -- never seen this myself.

Comment: That tab also just appeared in my phpstorm and I don't know what it is. It simply has a button to generate a random number. It seems as if some plugin developer had been doing some testing and left it there before uploading the plugin to production

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in WebStorm. Turns out it's related to plugin `Dark-Themes` by shubham076. Uninstalling the plugin made `MyToolWindow` go away